# ClassCastException: Can't cast oracle.sql.ARRAY to oracle.sql.ARRAY in JBoss 7.1.1.Final

Tags: spring, oracle, oracle11g, jboss7.x, classloader

DemoApp is spring integration project deployed in jboss 7.1.1.Final

The result returned from a stored procedure contains object of oracle.sql.ARRAY (object referring ojdbc jar of jboss module)

And I tried converting to oracle.sql.ARRAY which throwing exception

Code:

```
URL resultJarLocation= resultMap.get("returnObj").getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
URL appJarLocation = oracle.sql.ARRAY.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
System.out.println("resultJarLocation : " + resultJarLocation);
System.out.println("appJarLocation : " + appJarLocation);

oracle.sql.ARRAY returnObj=(oracle.sql.ARRAY)resultMap.get("returnObj");
```

EXCEPTION:

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.sql.ARRAY  cannot be cast to oracle.sql.ARRAY
```

The application ARRAY class is referring ojdbc jar in the deployed application.
where as result set ARRAY class referreing ojdbc jar jboss module
Sys Output:

```
resultJarLocation : jar:file:/<JBOSS_HOME>/modules/com/oracle/ojdbc6/main/ojdbc6.jar
appJarLocation : vfs:/<JBOSS_HOME>/bin/content/DemoApp.war/WEB-INF/lib/ojdbc6.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast between classes loaded by different classloaders. JVM distinguishes classes not only by name and package but also by the classloader used. In other words, from JVM perspective is like trying to cast from say String to Long; you cannot. 
The only think you can do is configuration.  Set up either for the same classloader to be used, or the classloaders to be in the same hierarchy, to take advantage of delegation.

I am not very familiar with JBoss (especially current versions) but I know it has (or used to have in the past) some very different classloading strategy than other application servers. Checking with its documentation on classloading would be my first option.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing the ojdbc jar's scope as 'provided' as this will not include the jar in the WEB-INF/lib.

And then added the Dependencic of jboss 7 module 'com.oracle.ojdbc6' in pom.. which will add the Dependencies attribute in META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file, as a result on deployment the jboss 7's ojdbc jar will be uses for object creation for both jboss and application, and the classloader will be the jboss's classloader.

Bellow are the code in pom.

1) Manifest entry :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifestEntries>
                <Dependencies>com.oracle.ojdbc6</Dependencies>
            </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

2) Dependency as Provided:

```
<dependency>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

META-INF/Manifest.MF file will be generated with dependency entry

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Dependencies: com.oracle.ojdbc6
Built-By: Mrinmoy
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_65
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.2.2
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
```